# Unable to use modify_account with pjsua

Tags: python, pjsip

I am attempting to create an account using pjsua and then modify that account, but it complains that an integer is required even when I use an integer.

**Here is my test code:**

```
lib = pj.Lib()
lib.init()
lib.create_transport(pj.TransportType.UDP, pj.TransportConfig(0))
lib.create_account(pj.AccountConfig('127.0.0.1', '1234'))
mailbox = 5678
lib.modify_account('acc.info().uri', pj.AccountConfig('127.0.0.1', '%d' %
int(mailbox)))
```

**Here is the error:**

Traceback (most recent call last):

File `./test.py`, line 29, in

```
lib.modify_account('acc.info().uri', pj.AccountConfig('127.0.0.1', '%d' % int(mailbox)))
```

File `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pjsua.py`, line 2354, in modify_account

```
err = _pjsua.acc_modify(acc_id, acc_config._cvt_to_pjsua())
```

> TypeError: an integer is required
>
> Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute
>   'destroy'" in > ignored

Comment: Please format your code. More info on how to do this, here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: modify account is used to modify the existing account. set the default account first and modify the account with your new details